# How to find references (or usages) in Atom editor?

Tags: javascript, ide, atom-editor

One of the most famous features of IDEs is as you know finding references (or usages) of variables, functions or classes in a project. I have been trying Atom Atom) for a while. I like it so far. But, I could not find a way to access to references (or usages) of var/function or a class in JavaScript code. Isn't this feature available in Atom editor? I give two examples below.

a) In the following simple code, Atom does not take me the declaration of "title". I am making "Go to Declaration" by right clicking on the word "title"

```
Template.docAddForm.events({
    'submit .js-add-doc':function(event){
         const title = event.target.doctitle.value; // The declaration of "title"
         Session.set('docTitle', title);  // Cannot access the declaration of "title" in Atom
    }
});
```

Another example. I cannot access to declaration of **Users** object which is a Collection declared in imported "commons.js" in the following code.

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import {Users} from '../lib/commons.js';

/** PUBLICATIONS **/
Meteor.publish('users', function () {
  return Users.find({}, {fields: {_id: 0}});
});
```

Comment: if the answer solved your problem, please accept. Otherwise let me know how I can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: For the goto package to work, you have to generate a `.tags` file in the root of your project. Enable the [`symbol-gen`](https://atom.io/packages/symbol-gen) package to do so within Atom, and then use `cmd-alt-g` to generate the symbols. Then the `goto` shortcuts (and right click > "Go to Declaration") will work.

---

The [goto](https://atom.io/packages/goto) package should be enabled by default to jump to variable instantiation.

> `cmd-r` - Goto File Symbol
>
> `cmd-shift-r` - Goto Project Symbol
>
> `cmd-alt-down` - Goto Declaration

As for finding variable usage, I believe that would depend on the language you're using. For example, [`atom-ternjs`](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ternjs) would show you variable usage (and a lot more) for JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you Mitch for the suggestions. I tried but neither (default and ternjs) has worked. I don't understand the problem. Accessing to declarations and usages is a core feature for an editor and there must be a way for it at Atom, too. I added a sample code to the question above.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your example? I'm assuming you are placing your cursor on `Users` just before `.find` and expecting to use some keystroke to take you somewhere. Do you want to jump to the line that says `import {Users}...`? Or to somewhere within the `../lib/commons.js` file that references `Users`?

Comment: Pls see example-a in the question.

Comment: Thank you for the details @MitchLillie. I installed  symbol-gen  and generate the symbols (and generate the .tags file). But it didnt work either. I have the following packages installed (related with symbol generation)
-- symbol-gen 1.3.1
-- symbols-view 0.115.2
-- atom.ternjs 0.18.2

Comment: Can you post the .tags file it generated? And try restarting Atom? @GokhanKaradag

Comment: What is the cmd key in linux?